# unix timestamp to boost::posix_time::ptime

Tags: c++, boost, unix-timestamp, boost-date-time

I need to convert double with number of seconds since the epoch to `ptime`. I'm prety sure there must be an easy way to do this, but I couldn't find anything. Thanks.

Edit: The original timestamp is floating point. I can't change it and i don't want to lose the sub-second precision.

Comment: You sure you need a double? I think it fits in a int.

Comment: Yes, I need double -- it's a part of an interface that I can't change. If it's a number of seconds then you can't capture the fractional part ... and http://xkcd.com/607/ :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

after some fiddling around i came up with this:

```
ptime(date(1970, 1, 1), time_duration(0, 0, 0, time_duration::ticks_per_second() * 1234567890.0987654321))
```

I'm not sure this is the best solution, but it seems to do what i need.

Comment: Actually this is the best solution, because it doesn't assume that time_t is based on 1970-01-01. (Although maybe it could be split over a couple of lines :-) )

Answer (score 8):

Use the [`from_time_t()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#ptime_from_funcs) conversion function. A `time_t` is a UNIX timestamp, i.e. the number of seconds since the epoch.

Comment: time_t can't contain fractional parts of seconds, but thanks for the answer

Comment: `time_t` is UNIX timestamp on almost any platform, but C++ standard does not specify this behavior. So be careful with this translation.

Answer (score 8):

For a machine that has boost date/time compiled to the default level of microsecond resolution, try this:

```
double ts = 1250524800.5;
// Use floor() here if seconds are always positive.
time_t secondsSinceEpoch = floor(ts);
long microsecondsSinceSecond =
    floor((ts - static_cast<double>(secondsSinceEpoch)) * 1000000);
boost::posix_time::ptime result =
    boost::posix_time::from_time_t(secondsSinceEpoch);
boost::posix_time::time_duration fractionalSeconds(0, 0, 0,
                                                   microsecondsSinceSecond);
result += fractionalSeconds;
cout << "Time stamp is " << result << endl;
```

The output for this is "Time stamp is 2009-Aug-17 16:00:00.500000" on my linux box.

Comment: You probably want to add a `+0.5` to your `microsecondsSinceSecond` calculation to get round-to-nearest.  Otherwise you'll suffer from truncation bugs.  Though... I guess anybody who cares about the difference of a half of a microsecond probably wouldn't store a timestamp in a `double` in the first place.

Comment: @Tom: You are correct here, although I expect that anyone who really cares about this level of resolution will configure their Boost distribution for nanosecond support and make appropriate changes to the code above.