# How to convert a fractional epoch timestamp (double) to an std::chrono::time_point?

Tags: c++, c++11, unix-timestamp, boost-date-time, c++-chrono

I have a fractional epoch timestamp, represented as `double`, that I would like to convert to an appropriate `std::chrono::time_point`. The epoch is the usual UNIX epoch since 1/1/1970. I know that there exists `std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t`, but a `time_t` does not have a fractional part. What would be the best way to do this with C++11 means?

This question is related to [unix timestamp to boost::posix_time::ptime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167518/unix-timestamp-to-boostposix-timeptime), except that it's asking for the C++11 rather than Boost version of it.

Comment: Have you read over [N2661](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2661.htm)?

Comment: "(...) fractional epoch timestamp, represented as `double`" What units? Do you know the epoch?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: it is the standard UNIX epoch since 1/1/1970.

Comment: If nanoseconds is good enough, try `std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(x) + std::chrono::nanoseconds(1e9*std::fmod(x,1))` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming the epoch is the same as a known `clock` type you can use a duration with a `double` representation and convert to the duration used by that clock.

```
// change period to appropriate units - I'm assuming seconds
typedef std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<1>> d_seconds;

d_seconds since_epoch_full(324324.342);
auto since_epoch = std::chrono::duration_cast<clock::duration>(since_epoch_full);
clock::time_point point(since_epoch);
```

This should be ok for any calculation involving that clock, since you're using the same precision as the clock, but it may lose some of the precision in the conversion. If you don't want to lose that you'll have to use a `time_point` specialization that uses that `double`-based duration type. And then use that in your calculations (of course, with all the caveats of floating-point math).

```
typedef std::chrono::time_point<clock, d_seconds> d_time_point;
```

However, this will complicate any calculations involving that same clock, as it will require conversions. To make this easier, you can build your own clock wrapper that does the conversions and use that:

```
template <typename Clock>
struct my_clock_with_doubles {
    typedef double rep;
    typedef std::ratio<1> period;
    typedef std::chrono::duration<rep, period> duration;
    typedef std::chrono::time_point<my_clock_with_doubles<Clock>> time_point;
    static const bool is_steady = Clock::is_steady;

    static time_point now() noexcept {
        return time_point(std::chrono::duration_cast<duration>(
                   Clock::now().time_since_epoch()
               ));
    }

    static time_t to_time_t(const time_point& t) noexcept {
        return Clock::to_time_t(typename Clock::time_point(
                             std::chrono::duration_cast<typename Clock::duration>(
                                 t.time_since_epoch()
                             )
                        ));
    }
    static time_point from_time_t(time_t t) noexcept {
        return time_point(std::chrono::duration_cast<duration>(
                   Clock::from_time_t(t).time_since_epoch()
               ));
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you mind elaborating where the loss in precision originates? Also, can the clock type in `d_time_point` be arbitrary?

Comment: @Matthias: the loss in precision is because the clock's native duration type may not be able to represent the exact duration you have as `double`. As an example, if the duration is 10.5 seconds, but the clock uses an integral duration with period 1 second, it will become 10s or 11s when converted. Ideally, the clock type in `d_time_point` should be one with the same epoch.

Comment: @DeadMG: `324324.342` is an exemplary fractional timestamp.